# How to set up connectivity between virtual machines on different VMware dedicated servers?

Tags: vpn, vmware-esxi, hetzner

I have 3 dedicated servers at Hetzner with VMware vSphere.

```
vmware01: 192.168.2.0/24
vmware02: 192.168.3.0/24
vmware03: 192.168.4.0/24
```

All servers use Pfsense and have WAN and LAN IP-addresses.
Some virtual machines are accessible via the WAN via manually configured port forwarding.

Most virtual machines don't have external IP addresses, but I'd like to configure vmware01/vmware02 to back-up to vmware03.

I could set up port forwarding manually to expose the needed ports from the WAN interface, but I'd rather keep traffic internal.

What would be the most logical solution?

In the past I only had vmware01/vmware02 and set up an OpenVPN connection between the pfsense01 and pfsense02 virtual machine, but in the future there might be 10+ servers and it wouldn't make sense to set up a separate VPN between all 10 dedicated servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hetzner's [vSwitch](https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/network/vswitch) feature to set up a VLAN that connects to each of your root servers. You can use a VLAN ID between 4000 and 4091. Then on each server you will configure the VLAN to have any networking configuration you wish.

Comment: I've been using Hetzner's vSwitch for one of my clients. Worked great. I've done the migration from one server to the other with no issues.